# How can I know the args passed to flask_script's Manager

Tags: python, flask, flask-script

I have a flask application, in one of its script commands I want to know what's the args passed to the Manager (not the command itself), how can I do that?

```
$ cat manage.py

#!/usr/bin/env python

from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager

app = Flask(__name__)

manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_option("-d", "--debug", dest="debug", action="store_true")

@manager.option('-n', '--name', dest='name', default='joe')
def hello(name):
    # how can I know whether "-d|--debug" is passed in command line
    print("hello", name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

If I run:

```
$ python manage.py --debug hello
```

I want to detect whether `'--debug'` is passed via command line args within the func of `hello`. I can't just change

```
manager.add_option("-d", "--debug", dest="debug", action="store_true")
```

to the decorator verion of:

```
@manager.option('-d', '--debug', action='store_true', dest='debug')
@manager.option('-n', '--name', dest='name', default='joe')
def hello(name, debug=False):
```

because `'-d|--debug'` is shared by many commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Global options are passed not to command, but to app-creating function.

See [add-option](https://flask-script.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask_script.Manager.add_option) docs.

> For this to work, the manager must be initialized with a factory function rather than a Flask instance. Otherwise any options you set will be ignored.

So you need to do something like

```
app = Flask(__name__)

def init_manager(debug):
    app.debug = debug
    return app

manager = Manager(init_manager)
```

And then access `app.debug`